# "scroll-snap-type" example using the whole window?

Tags: css, scroll, scroll-snap-type

All the examples I find online are for small scrolling boxes displayed within another page. I want to **snap the whole window/viewport** to some divs that are stacked vertically. For example:

```
[ content, scroll normally ]
[ "scroll snap" to this div ]
[ "scroll snap" to this div ]
[ "scroll snap" to this div ]
[ content, scroll normally ]
```

To clarify, there is no "fixed" content and the divs I want to "snap" are just rectangles like maybe 300x700.

I tried adding `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` to the parent container of the divs, doesn't work in Firefox 69. I also tried adding `scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;` to the "body and "html" and that doesn't work either. Can you show me any example using "scroll-snap-type" on the whole window?

I gave up and looked for a Javascript alternative, but it seems like development of Javascript solutions slowed/stopped after this was added to browsers with CSS. I tried "Scrollify" for jQuery but it has glitches and doesn't work that well.

The code would look something like this.

```
<style>
  #container { scroll-snap-type: y mandatory; }
  #container div { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 700px; 
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
</style>

<div>this content scrolls normally</div>
<div id="container">
  <div>snap to here</div>
  <div>snap to here</div>
  <div>snap to here</div>
</div>
<div>this content scrolls normally</div>
```

Why doesn't this work?

I found an example of what I'm trying to do... https://snap.glitch.me/product.html but I'm looking for a more barebones example so I can figure out what my code is missing. Supposedly, the only two required CSS elements are "scroll-snap-type" and "scroll-snap-align" but it seems like something else is required to make this work.

Comment: If I understand this question correctly, couldn't `position: sticky;` work for you?

Comment: @kawnah for the sake of my question, assume there's no z-index or "fixed" elements on the page.

Comment: I've got one example here, Maybe it will help.
(https://codepen.io/DivyaPatel/full/OqweBP)

Comment: @DivyaPatel Sorry, you didn't read my question. I want to scroll the whole viewport, not just a little scrolling box.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Benr783 No, it was low priority.

Comment: Its very easy to wrap your content in a 100vh div and make that achieve what you need with scroll snap. 

You can add snap positions to the elements that you want to snap and leave the others.

Scroll snap really should work in firefox and all browsers.

Comment: @Sharkfin If you post a solution, I'll try it and mark it solved. FWIW, seems like YouTube uses this effect now for their short videos.